# недопонимание при присваивании указателей

Tags: c, указатели

Всем привет! Продолжаю свое изучение языка Си маленькими шажками, и вот начал такую тему как "указатели". Сначала было понятно, по ресурсам в интернете дошел до раздела по изменению типа указателя, и вот тут начались появляться вопросы.. Томить не буду, но присваивание ниже я совсем не понимаю: почему у первого указателя такое большое значение, а не 10? почему второй и четвертый указатели показывают, по сути, правильное значение, в отличие от остальных? неужели все настолько сильно зависит от типа данных?

```
#include <iostream>#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
        int a = 1;
        float b = 2;
        double c = 3;
        int* p1 = &a;
        float* p2 = &b;
        double* p3 = &c;
        void* p4 = NULL;

    printf("a=%d\tb=%f\tc=%lf\n", a, b, c);
    *p1 = 5;
    *p2 = *p2 * *p1;
    *p3 = sqrt(*p3);
    printf("a=%d\tb=%f\tc=%lf\n", a, b, c);
    printf("*p1=%d\t*p2=%f\t*p3=%lf\n\n", *p1, *p2, *p3);
    p1 = (int*)p2;
    p3 = (double*)p2;
    p4 = p2;
    printf("p1=%p\tp2=%p\tp3=%p\tp4=%p\n", p1, p2, p3, p4);
    printf("*p1=%d\t*p2=%f\t*p3=%f\t*(float*)p4=%f\n\n", *p1, *p2, *p3, *(float*)p4);

}
```

Comment: http://scrutator.me/post/2015/11/26/pointers_demystified_p1.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения процессора, указатель - это всего лишь адрес в памяти первого байта данных, на которые собственно ссылается этот указатель. А тип указателя говорит компилятору о том, как именно эти данные интерпретировать. Так, объявление `int* p1` говорит компилятору о том, что данные, на которые ссылается указатель `p1`, являются числом типа `int`. А объявление `float* p2` означает, что данные по указателю `p2` - это число типа `float`. А теперь посмотрите внимательно на ваше присваивание:

```
p1 = (int*)p2;
```

После выполнения этой строки кода, указатели `p1` и `p2` будут содержать одинаковый адрес, а значит будут ссылаться на один и тот же блок данных. Только при обращении к этому блоку через `p2`, он будет интерпретироваться как `float`, а через `p1` - как `int`. Через `p2` вы получили по этому адресу число `10.0` в формате, соответствующему типу `float`. Если представить это число в виде шестнадцатиричной последовательности байт, то оно будет выглядеть так: `41 20 00 00`. А если трактовать эти данные не как `float`, а как `int`, то это и будет как раз то большое число `1092616192`, что вывелось на экран при обращении к нему через указатель `p1`.

Подведу итог: при обращении к некоторому блоку данных типа **A** через указатель, ссылающийся на тип данных **B**, *приведения типа **A** к типу **B***, т.е. преобразования их из одного формата в другой *не происходит*! Просто данные типа **A** трактуются так, как будто они имеют тип **B**. Нужно быть очень осторожным с подобным "жонглированием" указателями, т.к. это легко может привести к ошибкам времени выполнения программы!